# UIPopoverView with UITableView sections keyboard hiding on background touch

Tags: uitableview, xcode4.2, uipopover

I am using popover view window's in my app. I want to hide keyboard when I touch background.
I have tried but that code is not working for popover view and is working fine for normal view.
Can any one help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide keyboard with controller, try to set the delegate for your UIPopoverController and execute your keyboard-hiding code in following delegate method:
-(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController